# php hex to dec with math functions is returning different results

Tags: php

For converting long values from `hex` to `dec`, I'm using a function from the comments at php.net:

```
function bchexdec($hex)
{
    $dec = 0;
    $len = strlen($hex);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
        $dec = bcadd($dec, bcmul(strval(hexdec($hex[$i - 1])), bcpow('16', strval($len - $i))));
    }
    return $dec;
}
```

Why does the function sometimes return the number with ending zeros?

For example, if I convert `c4b03b0a103b7d6ee7199930ad8c27bd`, it sometimes returns

> 261443728880417560465069440558290446269

and sometimes

> 261443728880417560465069440558290446269.0000000000

What's the catch?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Please give a link to some online IDE's to show both results.

Comment: Hi, you can try it here: https://ideone.com/2jUQeY. It seems that is server side problem, because on that IDE result is always without ending zeros...

Comment: Starting simple: Have you restarted your server? Also make sure you only use the code above and don't have any other code in your script while testing it.

Comment: Then I can't help you, since I also can't reproduce the problem anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, *this* should not output any fractional parts (including zero's)

```
$dec = bcadd(
    $dec, 
    bcmul(
        strval( hexdec($hex[$i - 1]) ), 
        bcpow('16', strval($len - $i) )
    )
);
// bcadd($left_operand, $right_operand, $scale = 0)
```

Simply because you're not setting the 3rd parameter of `bcadd`:

> **scale**
>   This optional parameter is used to set the number of digits after the decimal place in the result. If omitted, it will default to the scale set globally with the bcscale() function, or fallback to 0 if this has not been set.

So, unless there is some part of your code **explicitly** setting:

```
bcscale(10)
```

you won't get that reproduced.

Here are some links to [`bcadd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) and [`bcscale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php).

This is an example:

```
$a = array();
$a['x1'] = bchexdec('c4b03b0a103b7d6ee7199930ad8c27bd');
bcscale(10);
$a['x2'] = bchexdec('c4b03b0a103b7d6ee7199930ad8c27bd');
print_r($a);
// Array
// (
//    [x1] => 261443728880417560465069440558290446269
//    [x2] => 261443728880417560465069440558290446269.0000000000
// )
```